# How to use python to get "next page" on google?

Tags: python, google-chrome

Assume I am searching key words "python%20scrape" on google, how do I know if I can move to the next page? and how can I do so using python?

My current code is:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import mechanize
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.addheaders = [('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0')]
br.set_handle_robots(False)

html = br.open('http://google.com/search?q=python%20scrape')
html = html.read().lower()
```

What codes should I use next?

Comment: Sorry ... Anyway, I was editing my question when you voted my question down :D

Comment: What's not working? Where are you stuck? Am I understanding correctly that you want to extract the "next page" link from the HTML?

Comment: There are 645000 results if I search so on google. How can I move to the next page? ...Don't think the same link will work

Comment: **Currently** (and Google changes these things), you can use `start=N` as a URL parameter to start showing results at the `N`th result (usually there are 10 per page)

Answer (score -1):

Modify the start GET parameter of your request to change the results which show on the page.
For example,

```
https://www.google.com/#q=python%20scape&start=0
```

will show the first 10.

```
https://www.google.com/#q=python%20scape&start=10
```

will show the next 10 and so on.